# XSLT, how to fetch and output combined elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Dear community,
it would be great if you could give me an advice on how to transform this:

```
<div>  
something  
   <title>   this title  </title>  
    something else  
</div>
```

into

```
<div>  
<title1>
something  </title1>  
<title2>  this title  </title2>  
<title3>  something else  </title>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the substring-before/after method cannot be used as there is an inner element inside div. Moreover, copy-of seems like it doesn't work with substring either. Do you have any advice on how to transform the above xml?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that produces a closer (than other solutions) result to the wanted, and is at the same time slightly more general. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="div/text()|div/*">
        <xsl:element name="title{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(self::text())"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <title1>something</title1>
    <title2> this title </title2>
    <title3>something else</title3>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alejandro - Note that once I edited it became clear that there is additional whitespace in the source doc. This isn't really your fault, since it wasn't originally clear and the OP probably doesn't realize (or care) that whitespace can be significant.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is a little bit more precise and more general at the same time**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/node()">
  <xsl:element name="title{position()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="translate(self::text()|node(), '&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<div>
something      
    <title>   this title  </title>
     something else
</div>
```

**a more closer to the desired result is produced** (only NL or CR characters are converted to space):

```
<div>
   <title1> something           </title1>
   <title2>   this title  </title2>
   <title3>      something else </title3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I just realized that my output doesn't match yours. 
 But @Alejandro's solution is perfect, so I hope you won't be too upset about this one.

---

I came up with this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/text()|div/title/text()">
        <xsl:element name="title{position()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
    <title1>something</title1>
    <title1>this title</title1>
    <title3>something else</title3>
</div>
```